# Remove strings that contain digits and convert others in upper case and separate them with comma

Tags: c++, stl

I've almost finished this task but have a little trouble in result. Here's the problem description:
Given a vector of strings, please implement the following 2 functions to process and output it:

1. process(): remove strings that contain digits and convert others in upper case
2. output(): print the strings and separate them with comma.
   Hints:
3. If possible, manipulate the vector elements in place to avoid copying vector.
4. It is encouraged to leverage STL functions/algorithms.
   Expected Output:
   ==========================================

   Before: abc, 123, 456, xyz

   After: ABC, XYZ

But my code caused the input is not as expected

```
before process: abc, 123, 456, xyz,
after process: ABC, XYZ,
```

Please tell me how to remove the comma in the end of string in both case before/after process

Here's my code:

```
#include <algorithm> 
#include <cctype> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
 

void process(std::vector<std::string>& v)
{
    
    // Remove strings that contain digits
    for(std::string &s : v)
        s.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(s), std::end(s), 
                           [](unsigned char ch) { return std::isdigit(ch); }), 
            s.end()); 
 
    // Convert other characters into upper case
// std::toupper has several overloads
// template <class charT> charT toupper(charT, const locale&)
// int toupper(int ch)
// So taking its address might be complicated.
// We can use lambda to let compiler found the right overload:
// (In addition, as char might be signed or not, and toupper expects unsigned char value (or EOF))
    for(std::string &s : v)
    {
        std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), 
        [](unsigned char c){ return std::toupper(c); }); 
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void output(std::vector<std::string>& v) 
{
    for(std::string &str : v)
        if(str != "\0")
            std::cout << str << ", "; 
        
}

int main() 
{ 
    std::vector<std::string> v = { "abc", "123", "456", "xyz" };
    std::cout << "Before: "; output(v);
    process(v);
    std::cout << "After: "; output(v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `process()` function is not completely removing the strings with digits, but make them empty string. Is it necessary to keep index of the vector, or is it allowed to pick them out of the vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, good old syntax is a good thing.

```
void output(std::vector<std::string>& v)  {
    
    // clean array
    size_t n = v.size();
    while(n--) if(v[n] == '\0') v.erase(v.begin() + n);
    
    // print words
    for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << v[i];
        if(i < (v.size() - 1) std::cout << ", "; 
    }
}
```

another method

```
void output(std::vector<std::string>& v)  {

    // clean array
    size_t n = v.size();
    while(n--) if(v[n] == '\0') v.erase(v.begin() + n);

    // print words
    size_t max = v.size() - 1;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < max; ++i) 
        std::cout << v[i] << ", "; 

    std::cout << v[max];
}
```

Comment: This would still print a last comma in case the last value of the vector is empty. It needs to know what is the last printable value, not the last value.

Comment: @carce-bo solved.

Answer (score 1):

Print first element of your vector. Make comma be printed with next elements.

```
void output(const std::vector<std::string> &v) {
    // find 1st not-empty string
  auto iter = std::find_if(v.cbegin(), v.cend(),
                           [](const auto &s) { return !s.empty(); });

  if (iter == v.cend()) {
    return;  // return if all of v are empty strings
  }

  std::cout << *iter;  // print 1st one
  ++iter;

  // print comma and next string if not empty
  for (; iter != v.cend(); ++iter) {
    if (!iter->empty()) {
      std::cout << ", " << *iter;
    }
  }

  std::cout << '\n';
}
```